# How does jquery-ui-draggable allow for the use of position:relative?

Tags: javascript, position, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I am working on updating my own draggable script and I am wondering how jquery-ui allows for you to have the position of an element set to relative and still allows for you to move it without affecting any of the elements around it that are also positioned relatively and floated?

As of right now my current script takes any element and gets its position but then sets it to absolute when you drag it, as a result all elements around it end up shifting to take its place.

My only two ideas are to:

a) Automatically set all elements on the page to position:absolute when I move one that's draggable (seems really inefficient).

b) Create an invisible copy of the current element that will remain in the exact spot.

and the to essentially implement:

```
var e = document.getElementById('div');
console.log(document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(e, null).getPropertyValue("position"));
```

from which I can determine if either step a or b is even necessary at all.

However, from what I can tell, to me it seems like jquery-ui-draggable does neither of these.

**Here is an example of this using jquery-ui-draggable: http://jsfiddle.net/aNk6e/17/**

How can I accomplish that same effect?

Comment: >Create an invisible copy of the current element that will remain in the exact spot.

I've seen this done before to achieve this effect

Comment: I plan to use that as a last resort, however, I kind of want to learn all my options, and surely there is a better way. I'm pretty sure that that's not how jquery-ui does it because I checked to see if any elements had been added to the document and there were none added.

Comment: can you give a link to a demo that shows this with `position:relative`?

Comment: Here, this shows it with float:left as well: http://jsfiddle.net/aNk6e/17/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how `position: relative` works.  The element still affects the document as though it was in its original position, but can be moved.

Consider this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/aNk6e/18/

Notice how the other two items are still affected as though the element were in its original position but the element is moved.

By simply manipulating `top` and `left` you can move the element around without affecting other elements in the document flow.

Comment: Wow, I feel like an idiot for not remembering that when I wrote my code.  Okay then now what's the best way to get whether the position of the element is relative or absolute? assuming the style-sheet will always be external? I know the way I posted above works for the newest versions of all browsers, is there a more compatible way?